# PNG image not getting resized in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, png

[image: in IE 10][image: in normal browser]

Hi,

I am using png image in my code.the png image is rendering fine in all browsers except ie 10,in IE its showing full size of the image,please look at the sample.

the code i am using is as under:

```
<div onclick="window.location='../Tutor/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm.php';" style="background-color:
                            #ff8080 !important;display: table; width:400px;height: 80px; overflow: hidden;">
                                <div onclick="window.location='../Tutor/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm.php';" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <div style="text-align:center" onclick="window.location='../Tutor/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm.php';">
                                        <a href="../Tutor/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm.php"><h4 style="color:white;">&nbsp;<img src="images/tutor.png" align="middle" height="50px" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="50px"><b>SignUp As a Tutor!</b></h4> </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


<img src="images/tutor.png" align="middle" height="50px" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" width="50px">
```

I tried few things but couldnot get the expected result.
any help would be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: how about percentages instead of pixels?for width and height

Comment: are you sure?did you made the changes like width="40%" like wise

Comment: yes i did made the changes but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Add a "height: auto;" into img style. IE need it .

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do that with pixels or either percentages try this

```
<img src="images/tutor.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
```

or else just refer to this CSS [keywords](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css/keywords.html)